# How to print infinity nested categories in dropdown (select) menu in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have this `category` table:

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Programming | 0 |
| 2 | History | 0 |
| 3 | PHP | 1 |
| 4 | Javascript | 1 |
| 6 | World history | 2 |
| 7 | jQuery | 4 |
| 8 | AJAX | 4 |
| 9 | Europe | 6 |
| 10 | American | 6 |
| 16 | ajax nested | 8 |

Here is how I get categories in **controller**:

```
$categories = Category::where('parent_id', '=', 0)->with('childs')->get();
```

And **Model Category:**

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }

    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I want to output categories, like this:

```
<select>
<option id="1">Programming</option>
<option id="3">Programming -> PHP</option>
<option id="4">Programming -> Javascript</option>
<option id="7">Programming -> Javascript -> jQuery</option>
<option id="8">Programming -> Javascript -> AJAX</option>
<option id="16">Programming -> Javascript -> AJAX -> ajax nested</option>
<option id="2">History</option>
<option id="6">History -> World history</option>
<option id="9">History -> World history -> Europe</option>
<option id="10">History -> World history -> American</option>
</select>
```

Which looks like:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri7aO.png)

**I am considering two options:**

1. Some service and clean php code with recursive function, which to return variable with complete HTML structure (select + options) and display that variable in template file.
2. Some Laravel way, which I don't know how to achieve.

Comment: Here is my answer for a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65635958/7181149

Comment: Although I merely displayed them in lists.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi Interesting, you do it on a level templates. I do something similar to render them in drop-down menus and it works fine - https://imgur.com/a/Dt3T7zQ
I tried to do something similar and for select tag (Recursive calling of templates), but cannot handle it for now.

Comment: So you only face issue on putting them in the selectbox yes?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi This is how I do it for menu, similar to your answer- https://pastebin.com/erDkMWZ9

I don't know how to handle arrows between them

Comment: Is this the way you want to display them? I just tested this on my local machine. https://ibb.co/XLVWfC0

Comment: @AhmadKarimi I posted image in question, but here it is again - https://imgur.com/a/3DwEeWv This i desired output. I have more than one level nested, and there can be more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your main blade template do like below. Here we first add the select box then loop through the categories. If a parent category has childs, then first the childs are added by calling another template and passing childs data to it.

```
<select name="" id="">     
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>

        @if (count($category->childs) > 0)
            @include('subcategories', ['subcategories' => $category->childs, 'parent' => $category->name])
        @endif

    @endforeach
</select>
```

Now, we have to create childs displaying template. Based on my example, the name should be **subcategories.blade.php**. In the child blade template, add the followings:

```
@foreach ($subcategories as $sub)
    <option value="{{ $sub->id }}">{{ $parent}} -> {{ $sub->name }}</option>

    @if (count($sub->childs) > 0)
        @php
            // Creating parents list separated by ->.
            $parents = $parent . '->' . $sub->name;
        @endphp
        @include('subcategories', ['subcategories' => $sub->childs, 'parent' => $parents])
    @endif
@endforeach
```

In the child template, we are recursively calling the child template itself over and over as long as each child has other childs.

And, here is the outcome on my machine: https://ibb.co/ynRB04h

Comment: I don't see any issue on your image.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could mark this as the accepted answer :)

Comment: You are right, it was my fault. When I get 15 rep, I will comeback and upvote it.